# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 mail -- Compilation Error

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, outlook-restapi

I am following [this entry at Exchange dev blog (MSDN)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx).

For the sample project published on GITHub, I'm getting following build errors, wondering which step I missed...

> Could not copy the file "AccessMailboxAsApp\Content\myappcert.pfx"
> because it was not found.
>
> Could not copy the file
> "AccessMailboxAsApp\Content\encryptionCert.pfx" because it was not
> found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to go through the "Configuring a X.509 public cert for your application" section of that blog.

EDIT:
It appears that the project file `AccessMailboxAsApp.csproj` that Matthias uploaded to GitHub has these files added in the `.\AccessMailboxAsApp\Content` folder, as seen in these lines:

```
<Content Include="Content\encryptionCert.pfx"> 
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
</Content> 
<Content Include="Content\myappcert.pfx"> 
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
</Content>
```

If you're using other certificate files, you can just remove these from the project. In Solution Explorer, expand the Content folder, then right-click these two files and choose "Exclude from Project".

Comment: But I finished these steps, is there anything missed?                                 

1. made a cert, 2. exported it, 3. used powershell to get three values, 4. download manifest json, 5. modified accordinly and then uploaded, 6. download again to verify

Comment: Yep, some stale data in the project file I think. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much, that concurred my modifications on the prj file.